# Uploading a file to sharepoint without a password

Tags: c#, .net, iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i am trying to upload a file to sharepoint with c# using the microsoft sharepoint client

i have no issues when i create my context and give it my username and password like this

```
                using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(spSite))
                {

                    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", fileLocation);

                    var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                    ctx.Credentials = credentials;
                    Web web = ctx.Web;

                    ctx.Load(user);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileLocation);
                    FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileLocation);

                    ctx.Load(web.Folders);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    Folder spFolder = web.Folders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(spListCleanName));

                    FileCreationInformation fci = new FileCreationInformation();
                    fci.Url = spSite + spLibraryName + file;



                    byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileLocation);
                    fci.Content = bytes;

                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File spFile = spFolder.Files.Add(fci);
                    spFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                }
```

but my issue comes in the network credentials part. is there a way to use the current users credentials (through iis or .net or anything) so that i don't have to ask for their password? since that isn't something we want to save in plain text anywhere.

thank you in advance

Comment: ASP.NET lets you use Windows Integrated Authentication to achieve SSO.

Comment: how would i use that? i tried using HttpClientHandler and setting the default credentials to true, but when i try to set it to my ctx object, it's null

Comment: Have a look at [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication)'s documentation; you need to set your authentication mode to `Windows`.

Comment: yeah, it actually is set to windows. would it matter if it's IIS express instead of regular IIS? cause it still isn't giving me my credentials

Answer (score 0):

Use the CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of NetworkCredential object.

This will use the users security context.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. seems like it only works for "NTLM", "Digest", "Kerberos", and "Negotiate" authentication types, i actually need it to be windows. when i inspected the credentials they were empty